# gap_init called from restricted origin

Tags: android, cordova, popup, phonegap-plugins

I have used barcodescanner plugin in my corodova app. I have a button "add". When I click the add button, one pop-up will occur and here we have one scan button.

It is showing following  error message:

> Ignoring exec() from previous page load.

It is working fine with android 4.4.4, but not with lower version.